# VS2010: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals . Working with templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, unresolved-external

Have a simple assignment with classes and templates for class, have searched on here and no solutions seem to fix the issue.  When I try to compile, this comes up:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup 1>c:\users\leanne\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PartC\Debug\PartC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Have a console project using an empty project. Can anyone help me find the issue?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename ItemType>
class Vec3
{
    ItemType x, y ,z;
public:
    Vec3<ItemType>(){x=0;y=0;z=0;}
    Vec3<ItemType>(const Vec3<ItemType>& other);
    Vec3<ItemType> operator+(Vec3<ItemType>);
    Vec3<ItemType> operator-(Vec3<ItemType>);
    bool operator==(Vec3<ItemType> other);
    Vec3<ItemType> operator=(Vec3<ItemType>);
    ~Vec3<ItemType>(){;}
};
template<typename ItemType>
Vec3<ItemType> Vec3<ItemType>::operator+(Vec3<ItemType> other)
{
    Vec3 temp;
    temp.x = x + other.x;
    temp.y = y + other.y;
    temp.z = z + other.z;
    return temp;
}
template<typename ItemType>
bool Vec3<ItemType>::operator==(Vec3<ItemType> other)
{
    if(x != other.x)
        return false;
    if(y != other.y)
        return false;
    if(z != other.z)
        return false;
    return true;
}
template<typename ItemType>
Vec3<ItemType> Vec3<ItemType>::operator-(Vec3<ItemType> other)
{
    Vec3 temp;
    temp.x = x - other.x;
    temp.y = y - other.y;
    temp.z = z - other.z;
    return temp;
}  
template<typename ItemType>
Vec3<ItemType> Vec3<ItemType>::operator=(Vec3<ItemType> other)
{
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z = other.z;
    return *this;
}
template<typename ItemType>
Vec3<ItemType>::Vec3(const Vec3<ItemType>& other)
{
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z= other.z;
}
template<typename ItemType>
int main()
{
    Vec3<int> v1;
    Vec3<int> v2(v1);
    Vec3<double> v3 = v2;
    v3 = v1+v2;
    v3 = v1-v2;
    if(v1==v2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: im getting a LNK 1120 unresolved external error so it won't compile

Comment: What is the *complete* error?  You left out the part that describes what's wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the symbol?

Comment: try to compile, this comes up:
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

1>c:\users\leanne\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PartC\Debug\PartC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: "unresolved external symbol _main" means that a non-templated function named `main` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting the error because you made `main` a template:

```
template<typename ItemType>
int main()
```

Please remove the `template<typename ItemType>`. `main` is not allowed to be a template.

Once you remove that, you will get errors on `Vec3<double> v3 = v2;` because `v2` is a `Vec3<int>` and cannot be converted to a `Vec3<double>`.

Comment: Amazing how the answer jumps out at you once all the relevant information is available.

Comment: yup, smacked my head the second I read it, thanks for the response!